# Java regex split xml xpath

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split the xpath as individual node.

My `xpath` is `/samp/lorem/ipsum/dolar[a/c]/imet(a)/data`

and I want to split like below:

```
/samp
/lorem
/ipsum
/dolar[a/c]
/imet(a)
/data
```

how to do this using java regex?

`String nodes = xpath.split("?");`

Comment: *"how to do this using java regex?"* You don't. XPath is a nested syntax. Java regex cannot do nested patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string using this regex,

```
(?=/)(?![^\[\]]*])
```

Here `(?=/)` regex marks the position at the beginning of every `/` and `(?![^\[\]]*])` negative look ahead ensures `/` inside square brackets is not selected for split.

Check this Java code,

```
String s = "/samp/lorem/ipsum/dolar[a/c]/imet(a)/data";
Arrays.stream(s.split("(?=/)(?![^\\[\\]]*])")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints,

```
/samp
/lorem
/ipsum
/dolar[a/c]
/imet(a)
/data
```